# ¿Es posible calcular coordenada de acuerdo a distancia?

Tags: python, google-maps, geolocalización, google-geocoding-api

Actualmente estoy usando la API de Google para obtener las coordenadas de un punto a otro. A través de Python, hice una función que retorna la distancia entra cada punto de forma consecutiva.

> Origen: (19.49614, -99.13266) Destino: (19.49614, -99.13266) Distancia: 936.041454542
>
> Origen: (19.49505, -99.13283) Destino: (19.49505, -99.13283) Distancia: 122.505551045

¿Es posible calcular las coordenadas de acuerdo a una cierta distancia?
Por ejemplo, desde la coordenada (19.49614, -99.13266) calcular una coordenada que este a 100mts de distancia?

Comment: Si consideras la coordenada de referencia como el centro de un círculo, hay una cantidad infinita de puntos que están a la misma distancia. La distancia que quieres encontrar es el radio de un círculo. Es recomendable al menos poner algo de código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es obtener coordenadas en la recta que pasa entre origen y destino entonces es relativamente simple (puntos de corte entre recta y circunferencia), en otro caso las coordenadas posibles serían infinitas como comenta Javier, ¿podrías aclarar esto?

Comment: Hola, gracias por sus respuestas, he encontrado la solución a la situación en esta pregunta.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823135/calculate-coordinate-by-distance-from-another-coordinate?answertab=oldest#tab-top